# Unable to use npm packages in deno deploy

Tags: npm, deno, deno-deploy

From Deno 1.28, deno natively supports npm packages. But when I try to deploy it in deno-deploy. It is downloading the dependency but fails with `Module not found`

I am trying to deploy an express application in deno deploy.

```
import express from "npm:express@4.18.2";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (_req: any, res: any) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(80, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on port 80");
});
```

But when I try to deploy it. I am getting the following error,

```
Cloning repository (100%)
Downloaded file:///src/server/index.ts
Downloaded npm:express@4.18.2
Error The deployment failed: Module not found "npm:express@4.18.2".
```

I can see the deployment step that express is downloaded. Can you someone please help me out on this ?

Answer (score 3):

This blog tell us "npm specifiers aren't currently supported in Deploy, but will be soon.":
https://deno.com/blog/npm-and-deno-anywhere